# Extract a list from a multidimensional list

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I am new to Python and I tried a lot of combinations, but I do not get the proper solution.
I have a list in a list:

```
AnimalLarge = ['Animal', 'Large', 20,30]
AnimalSmall = ['Animal', 'Small', 20,10]
HumanLarge = ['Human',' Large', 1, 2]
HumanSmall = ['Human', 'Small', 2, 2]
List = [AnimalLarge, AnimalSmall, HumanLarge, HumanSmall]
Search1 = 'Animal'
Search2 = 'Small'
ResultShouldBe = AnimalSmall
```

If I have e.g. the variable "Animal" and "Small", then I wanted to let the program "find" the proper combination "AnimalSmall", which contains "Animal, Small, 20, 10".
I know how to read out "manually" a list of a list or to read out single parameters from a list, but I am interested in reading out a list (with defined strings) within a list. I did a lot of trials with "for" and "in" and indexing, but they were all meaningless, so I did not post it here.
Could you please give me a hint, how to combine this? Sorry, I really spent quite some time on it and I do not get it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a for loop:

```
for l in List:
    if Search1 in l and Search2 in l:
        result = l
        break
```

or a list comprehension:

```
result = [l for l in List if Search1 in l and Search2 in l][0]
print(result)
```

**output:**

```
['Animal', 'Small', 20, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much!!!

(It looks so easy now, but i really could not manage the proper syntax, though looking on numerous documentations and forums in the web)